# Is this paragraph good or it needs correction?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I tried to write a paragraph about Facebook and I want to know it is good or it needs some changes.

> "Facebook is known as the biggest social media in the world; it has
>   millions of active users from all over the world. You can find a lot
>   of people who are interested to learn English or even native speakers.
>   There are thousands of pages and groups that teach English. It is the
>   best social media website to find English partners to practice with."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a few corrections:

> Facebook is the biggest social media in the world, *with millions of active users from all around the globe*. *On it* you can find both native English speakers as well as a lot of people who are interested in learning English. There are thousands of pages and groups that teach English, and is the best social media website to find English partners to practice with.

- "*with millions of active users from all around the globe*" - just to avoid the repetition of "world".
- I suspect that Facebook has more native English speakers than English learners, and for that reason I think you should name these first. Also, as you find *both* I prefer "and" over "or", which is used for *options*.
- I have joined the last two sentences with "and" because as it was, the paragraph seemed very fragmented.

Some of these choices are personal preferences, but it certainly sounds more natural this way. Written text that is too fragmented or that sounds unnatural when spoken can prevent the reader from retaining the information because they are too busy concentrating on the structure to absorb the message.

Comment: Could you tell me why you changed the "Facebook is known as" to active voice?

Comment: @AbuOmar "Known as" sounds like you're saying that is what everybody says about Facebook. I'm a Facebook user and I've never heard it called that, even though it may be true. I think it just sounds better if you either assert it as a fact (if that's what it is), or state that it is your opinion, or the opinion of others, whatever.